# Is there a way of opening an external .exe which doesn't pause the rest of the program? python

Tags: python, time, delay

I am writing a python program (3.8) which is automatically filling in certain options in a command window using a menu format. For example, when prompted with

[image]

It would fill the correct option (either 1 or 2).

Currently, the .exe file must be opened separately from the python file which is a hassle. To remove this I tried using subprocess like this.

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\file\location\that\ends\right\here\VSCaptureMP.exe'])
```

but it pauses the entire program until the .exe window is closed. The rest of the program (the automatic writing part) never gets to run when using this format.

I know there is an after module when using tkinter. Is there a similar option for this scenario?

Comment: How are you planning to use the result from the .exe? Can your program logically continue without the result? In tkinter you are following a completely different paradigm (event-driven programming) to control the program flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```
import subprocess

print("Hello")
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe"])
print("This is non-blocking!")
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thanks